# Start autossh on system startup

Tags: 16.04, ssh, startup, autossh

Is there any way to start `autossh` on startup, so that it starts and sets up the ssh tunnel before a user has even logged in? I boot Ubuntu to terminal, and I'd like that the `autossh` process starts automatically on startup so I can ssh in.

I've tried adding the command to `/etc/rc.local`, as well as to create a `/etc/init/*.conf` script. None of these seems to work.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: @George 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Something like [`@reboot autossh -D 9050 user@sshserver -fTNC` on crontab](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113951/349837)?

Answer (score 31):

Using `systemd` this can be done (sample `autossh` created for `mysql` access):

1. Create a systemd file using `nano` or `vim` or appropriate editor of choice:

   ```
   sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/autossh-mysql-tunnel.service
   ```
2. Add the following contents:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=AutoSSH tunnel service everythingcli MySQL on local port 5000
   After=network.target

   [Service]
   Environment="AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0"
   ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -NL 5000:localhost:3306 cytopia@everythingcli.org -p 1022

   [Install]
   WantedBy=multi-user.target
   ```
3. Reload `systemd`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
4. Start the `Autossh` service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start autossh-mysql-tunnel.service
   ```
5. Enable at `boot`:

   ```
   sudo systemctl enable autossh-mysql-tunnel.service
   ```
6. Check status with:

   ```
   sudo systemctl status autossh-mysql-tunnel
   ```

#### Note

> There is however an important thing to note about systemd and AutoSSH: -f (background usage) already implies `AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0`, however `-f` is not supported by `systemd`.

So in the case of `systemd` you need to make use of `AUTOSSH_GATETIME`

#### Source

- https://www.everythingcli.org/ssh-tunnelling-for-fun-and-profit-autossh/
- https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Comment: Thanks! I'm trying this, but when I run `sudo service reverse-ssh-tunnel.service status`, I get `Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)`. Researching this now :)

Comment: please do `sudo systemctl status reverse-ssh-tunnel` not `sudo service reverse-ssh-tunnel.service status`

Comment: Can I specify the SSL private key needed to authenticate with the other machine?

Comment: I believe you mean `autossh  -i /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa -R 22222:localhost:22 <user>@<remote_host>`

Comment: I needed to add `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` as well. Maybe I just need one of them, haven't tested them individually. Found this here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24689061/1211119. However, when I'm looking at the tty1 login screen (I boot to the terminal), the service hasn't yet created the tunnel. If I log in, the service starts.

Comment: Great answer. @ptf, thanks for commenting with the additional flags. Without those I was getting a 255 return value from ssh. Did you resolve the issue that the tunnel only initiates when you log in?

Comment: @Gabriel Hmm, I don't think so. I think I haven't look to much more at it.

Comment: Sometimes you want to run under a different user context. To do this: Add `User=username` to the `[Service]` section in the systemd file.

Comment: Why the "-M 0"  is needed?

Comment: This is the only one which is working for my raspberry pi project among all samples I read. However, after 2 days no activity, the connection is closed. When I view it with teamviewer the pi device is still online actually. Can you figure out why and what need to be fiixed here?

Comment: @ptf don't add both `-o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, add only `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new`. Not redundant and more secure.

Answer (score 0):

I added a `-N` to the command to get this to work. `-N` tells autossh to connect and do nothing. Without it my ssh session was logging in then immediately exiting. I also set it up to use a local user along with a `.ssh/config` file (`/home/myuser/.ssh/config`) which contains my tunnel rules.

```
# cat /etc/systemd/system/autossh.service

    [Unit]
    Description=AutoSSH service
    After=network.target
    
    [Service]
    Environment="AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0"
    User=myuser
    Group=myuser
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/autossh -N -M 0 -o "ServerAliveInterval 30" -o "ServerAliveCountMax 3" -i /home/myuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_np remoteid@remote
    RemainAfterExit=yes
    
    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target
```