# How to add a private IP address?

Tags: networking, server, proxy, dhcp

I added the following line to /etc/network/interfaces

```
auto ens7iface ens7 inet static address 192.168.1.2 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

when I do `systemctl restart networking` I get

```
Job for networking.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status networking.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I am trying to add a internal IP address to my ubuntu 16.04 VPS

Comment: If the VPS as a proxy server is going to be used externally from your network, then there *is* no Private IPv4 address.  Most VPSes don't have private networking, anyways; you'd be better off setting up a VPN and VPNing to the VPS so all your data flows through it rather than setting up a squid proxy, depending on your use case.

Comment: Nano is a text editor. You type nano followed by the path and name of the file you want to edit. Are you logged on to the VPS as root or yourself?  Please edit your question and add this information.

Comment: Thomas Ward, I could probably do that, but I really need to set it up as a proxy rather than VPN, I only need my browser to have the IP of the VPS, not the whole traffic.

Comment: User68186, I edited the question, and yes, I am logged in as root

Comment: After you open the file in question in nano, you will see the text in the file. Scroll down to the bottom and add the lines of text. Exit the nano editor by pressing CTRL+X. Nano will ask if you want to save the changes. Tyoe Y. Hit enter again to replace the old file. Let me know if this is what you wanted. I will write a full answer, which you can accept as correct. That will help others.

Comment: When I said scroLL down, I meant the down arrow key   .

Comment: Thank you for your help, I was able to edit the file, now it looks like this:
https://i.snag.gy/3Gh4pr.jpg

When I do sudo ifup eth1 command I get this:

https://i.snag.gy/vaSDZY.jpg

Comment: Please update your question with the new information. Please copy and paste terminal output in the question, don't put screenshots of text output in the question.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: Hello , @shiu'sho, probably for your needs you would be happy to use ssh connection with dynamic port forwarding, as it is [described here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113951/566421), instead of setup an entire proxy server.